# How to create Chef Package for Redhat. I have 2 rpms agents and 2 yaml files

Tags: chef, automation

1. Installation steps. There are two ELK agents to install:

   - Metricbeat

     1. Copy the attached file `metricbeat-6.0.0-x86_64.rpm` to the target server
     2. Execute the command: `sudo rpm -vi metricbeat-6.0.0-x86_64.rpm`
     3. Copy the attached file `system.yml` to `/etc/metricbeat/modules.d/`
     4. Copy the attached file `metricbeat.yml` to `/etc/metricbeat/`
     5. Execute the command: `sudo systemctl enable metricbeat`
     6. Execute the command: `sudo service metricbeat start`
   - Filebeat

     1. Copy the attached file `filebeat-6.0.0-x86_64.rpm` to the target server
     2. Execute the command: `sudo rpm -vi filebeat-6.0.0-x86_64.rpm`
     3. Execute the command: `sudo mv /etc/filebeat/module.d/system.yml.disabled /etc/filebeat/module.d/system.yml`
     4. Copy the attached file `filebeat.yml` to `/etc/filebeat/`
     5. Execute the command: `sudo systemctl enable filebeat`
     6. Execute the command: `sudo service filebeat start`

I want to Automate this using Chef. The Chef environment is ready and working.I want to deploy this binaries on 150 servers. Would be helpfull if someone explain with step by step.

Comment: Elastic.co provides repositories IIRC, just use yum_repository and package resources, add a template or file resource for the service and configuration and you should be fine. (that's what I do for Ubuntu boxes)

Comment: Hey. Thank you. Could you please an example how you do or take my example as itself.

Answer (score 1):

Very basic recipe exemple to install filebeat on ubuntu (I do use more or less the same approach for elasticsearch, kibana and logstash):

```
apt_repository 'elk' do
  uri 'https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/5.x/apt'
  distribution 'stable'
  components ['main']
  key 'https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch'
  cache_rebuild true
end

package 'filebeat' do
  action :upgrade # To keep up to date with releases from elastic.co
end

service 'filebeat' do
  action [:enable, :start]
end

template '/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml' do
  source 'filebeat.yml.erb'
  mode '0600'
  notifies :restart, 'service[filebeat]'
end
```

Basically, adding a repository, installing package, enabling and starting the service, render a config and restart the service when it changes. On ubuntu the package set the service scripts so I don't have to manage it here.

The template is my default configuration using some node attributes depending on environment. See https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html for more details on how to use them.

According to your question I would strongly sugest you to follow the tutorial paths at https://learn.chef.io to grasp the basics about chef.

Comment: Sure.. I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.nl/search?q=how%2Bto%2Bcreate%2Ba%2Bchef%2Bpackage

returns:

https://docs.chef.io/resource_package.html

and

https://docs.chef.io/resource_examples.html

The latter provides code snippets, like how to copy files:

> **Create a file from a copy**
>
> The following example shows how to copy a file from one directory to
>   another, locally on a node:
>
> ```
> file '/root/1.txt' do
>   content IO.read('/tmp/1.txt')
>   action :create
> end
> ```

More example could be found in [the supermarket](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/mysql). In order to write chef books one could investigate how some recipes are structured like [mysql](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/mysql).

Comment: Hey.Thank you.I want to know how to proceed.What I understood from the answer is. The above snippets creates a package after that I have to prepare a recipe?

Comment: Could you explain why you would like to use chef?

Comment: I am using it for deployment of the above binaries for all servers

Comment: Ok, but did you consider puppet, ansible or salt?

Comment: Hey. I already have an environment of chef

Comment: Hi, I could able to write cookbook and install filebeat rpm. However I am getting the below error while creating a template.                     
 Error executing action `create` on resource 'template[/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml]'
 ==================================================Chef::Exceptions::FileNotFound
    ------------------------------
    Cookbook 'ELK' (0.1.0) does not contain a file at any of these locations:
      templates/redhat-6.9/filebeat.yml.erb
      templates/redhat/filebeat.yml.erb
      templates/default/filebeat.yml.erb
      templates/filebeat.yml.erb

Comment: Could you add this to the question and format it?